# Pattern for Slf4j logger

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, slf4j

I am getting logs in the spring boots default pattern.

```
2017-02-10 15:39:01.111  INFO 24483 --- [ryBean_Worker-1] c.f.dashboard.services.SchedulerService  : Hello World!
```

I want to get the logs in this format

```
2017/02/10 11:24:37,771 [INFO] [http-nio-8080-exec-8] myMethod(myClass.java:38) - Hello World!
```

I have tried using this pattern

```
%sn %d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %r [%-5p] [%t] %M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

but is giving parse errors in the log lines.

```
%PARSER_ERROR[sn] 2017/02/10 09:41:25 12018 [INFO ] [schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1] %PARSER_ERROR[M] - Hello World!
```

Comment: I think the pattern is correct and there might be some other issue in code. Please refer the below URL. http://log4jtester.com/?p=%25sn+%25d%7Byyyy%2FMM%2Fdd+HH%3Amm%3Ass%2CSSS%7D+%25r+%5B%25-5p%5D+%5B%25t%5D+%25M(%25F%3A%25L)+-+%25m%25n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this in your application.xml

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"} [%p] [%t] %M\\(%F:%L\\) - %msg%n
```

Or in application.yml

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: '%d{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"} [%p] [%t] %M\(%F:%L\) - %msg%n'
```

For date pattern, the comma ',' character is interpreted as the parameter separator, the pattern HH:mm:ss,SSS will be interpreted as the pattern HM:mm:ss and the timezone SSS. If you wish to include a comma in your date pattern, then simply enclose the pattern between quotes. For example, %date{"HH:mm:ss,SSS"}

For method pattern, If you need to treat the parenthesis character as a literal, it needs to be escaped by preceding each parenthesis with backslash. Otherwise you will get parser error.

Rests are self explanatory.

Comment: 2017/02/10 16:48:44,287 [INFO] [main] logStarting\(StartupInfoLogger.java:48\2017/02/10 16:48:44,295 [DEBUG] [main] logStarting\(StartupInfoLogger.java:51\2017/02/10 16:48:44,295 [INFO] [main] logStartupProfileInfo\(SpringApplication.java:637\2017/02/10 16:48:48,209 [INFO] [main] log\(DirectJDKLog.java:179\2017/02/10 16:48:48,211 [INFO] [main] log\(DirectJDKLog.java:179\2017/02/10

Comment: I used it in yml file as .        
pattern:
    console: '%d{"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"} [%p] [%t] %M\\(%F:%L\\) - %msg%n'

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you please explain what did you change. Ive used the similar one earlier and got no line breaks

Comment: application.xml needed two backslash and application.yml needed only one for method pattern. probably you missed something like that.